# WPF ComboBox not responding to mouse

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a very weird problem with a WPF ComboBox. On one computer (and only one) in our company the WPF ComboBox refuses to respond to mouse events when the ComboBox drop down is open. When the user clicks on the ComboBox to make the drop down appear and tries to select an item, he/she gets no hover effects from mouse over. When the user clicks on an item, the drop down closes, but the item they clicked never gets selected. It seems like the ComboBox's drop down of items is not responding to any mouse events. This only happens on one computer in the entire company. Everyone else's program works just fine.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET Framework from 2.0 on up. I've tried disabling everything that is running in the background. I still have no luck getting it to work. I've even tried replacing the mouse. Every other program I try that has a ComboBox works fine, but the WPF one.

Here is the code for the ComboBox:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="3"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Configuration.Items}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Configuration.CurrentItem}"
          Style="{StaticResource inputStyle}" />

<Style x:Key="inputStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="TextBoxBasee.IsReadOnly" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" />
        </Triggers>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Does anyone have any idea on what is happening or how to solve it?

Comment: All machines are definitely running the same versions of framework, including service packs?  (Check the minor version on any of the System.dlls.
Can't really see that being the problem but worth eliminating.

Comment: Yup. I thought that same thing. Everyone is running .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: The style confuses me a bit.  Since ComboBox doesn't derive from TextBoxBase, I'm surprised the trigger would work.  Maybe if it somehow figures out to set respond to a ComboBox template containing a textbox.  Also, are you setting IsReadOnly somewhere in your code?

Comment: Also, is TestBoxBasee a typo?  I thought there was only TextBoxBase.

Comment: Yeah that is a typo. I use that style for all input controls to give them a margin and if it is a TextBoxBase, it will change the background. If it doesn't derive from TextBoxBase (ie ComboBox), that trigger gets ignored and nothing happens with the background on the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after formatting the computer and installing everything fresh, we still had the issue. It sounds silly but we replaced the video card and it fixed the problem. We even threw that card in another computer and it encountered the same problem. We also found an old driver, thinking that might be the culprit, but it still had an issue. So in case anyone else out there is having weird issues with WPF on one computer, try replacing the video card. It just might fix it.

Comment: Very weird problem. If you think the problem was from a hardware, than why don't you share the product name(or graphic chipset) of the bad graphic card? :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Windows 7. Another idea is to play around with the display settings. My solution was to set the program to run with 256 colors using the compatibility settings of its shortcut.