# Cant select value from combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I cant seem to select a value from a combobox. I've looked at the other questions/solutions, but none of the answers, nor questions, seems to be relevant to my problem.

In my view :

```
ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FileInstructions, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFileInstruction, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

In my viewModel:

```
    public FileInstructionSelectorControl(Action<FileInstruction> selectionChangedEvent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        //_selectionChangedEvent = selectionChangedEvent;
        SetFileInstructions();

        /*var myList = new List<string>() { "Bob" };
        FileInstructions = new ObservableCollection<string>(myList);*/
        SelectedFileInstruction = FileInstructions[0];
    }

    private void SetFileInstructions()
    {
        var instructions = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FileInstruction)).Cast<FileInstruction>();
        FileInstructions = new ObservableCollection<string>(instructions.Select(item => item.ToString()).ToList());
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _fileInstructions;
    public ObservableCollection<string> FileInstructions
    {
        get => _fileInstructions;
        set
        {
            _fileInstructions = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FileInstructions));
        }

    }

    private string _selectedFileInstruction;
    public string SelectedFileInstruction
    {
        get => _selectedFileInstruction;
        set
        {
            _selectedFileInstruction = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedFileInstruction));
            SelectionChanged();
        }
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public void SelectionChanged()
    {
        //_selectionChangedEvent(SelectedFileInstruction);
    }
```

As you can see, I've tried manually setting the selectedItem to the first item in the list, and it displays correctly
[image]

But I'm unable to select a new value from the comboBox. The list does populate, but it feels like the comboBox is locked/disabled, as I unable to get a drop-down when clicking the comboBox.

Edit :

I'm able to tab to the combo-box, and change the values with my keyboard, but not able to get the combobox to drop down with my mouse.

Comment: What you call "viewModel" is actually the code behind of your FileInstructionSelectorControl, right? As a note, it seems unnecessary to use ObservableCollection as type of the FileInstructions property, because you don't seem to ever add or remove elements to/from the collection. It's also unclear why you have this control at all. Is there anything else than the ComboBox in its XAML? How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: Correct, it's not -really- a viewmodel, but rather the codebehind. And yes, I understand that I could have used an IEnum. or List<>, the ObsColl was just an attempt to try something to get it working

Comment: As another note, it is redundant to set `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on both Bindings. It has no effect on the ItemSource binding, because an ItemsControl never updates the source of that Binding. The SelectedItem property binds two-way by default and already updates the source whenever its value changes.

Comment: You may however want to remove `DataContext = this` from the constrol constructor and add `RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}` to the ComboBox property Bindings.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens. Again, this was done due to just trying everything.

Comment: Besides all that, what you're showing here should work fine. At least, it works for me. There must be something you haven't shown us.

Comment: @Clemens, that didn't do the trick either. However, I noticed now that if I tab to the combobox, I can change the values with my keyboard, but not with the mouse. The problem is clearly not related to my bindings.

Comment: That's what I mean when I say "there must be something you haven't shown us". All the other notes weren't meant to fix your problem, but just remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue isn't related to binding, but what appears to be hardware related, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342200/wpf-combobox-not-responding-to-mouse)